# Python @properity autocomplete in atom editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, atom-editor

i was defining a @property in python using atom. So the autocomplete gave em this:

```
    def test():
    doc = "The test property."
    def fget(self):
        return self._test
    def fset(self, value):
        self._test = value
    def fdel(self):
        del self._test
    return locals()
test = property(**test())
```

Where test is the name I defined. I didnt understand what does this code do and how do i use it?
Is there a difference of using it instead the conventional way to use getter and setter in python?

i would be appreciate for some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text editor is just showing you the alternative way to use `property` without using a decorator. The example in the official Python documentation shows this as well. `property` itself is a class that takes keyword arguments of, `fget`, `fset`, `fdel`, and `doc`. In your example you have `test` return all the functions that match the keyword arguments and then use unpacking to feed them in as arguments. That is shown in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).